# Can skylanders mess up my laptop?

Tags: skylanders

my daughter put all her skylanders on top of my perfectly wonderful laptop and it crashed the next morning. Coincidence or not?

Comment: I say coincidence. all the Skylanders contain are NFC chips. I bet a cellphone can do more damage than that when placed on a laptop...

Comment: Completely coincidental.  You're stretching for a reason, since most crashes don't tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

So you mean she physically put the toys on top of the laptop, correct? The Skylanders toys work on RFID chips, and wouldn't have any effect on your laptop. Though you didn't explain in what way the laptop crashed, or really anything about the laptop itself, this would be purely coincidental.